# Pool liner loose after hard rainfall - wait for it to re-seat itself?

Tags: pool

Hi my pool liner went loose bc of excessive rainfall. In the past it re-seats itself. This time it’s pretty bad so I didn’t know if I needed to proactively push it back down.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guy near me has a "well" next to his fiberglass pool which he pumps dry or down to some level. He told me the installer told him this was necessary to keep the pool from being lifted by hydraulic pressure.

Comment: But do I just let it fall back in or manually push it

Comment: I doubt you would be able to push it back in place. There must be water behind it.